# Python base class that makes abstract methods definition mandatory at instantiation

Tags: python, oop

I have a base class that define a couple of empty methods. I would like to enforce/make mandatory the definition of these methods in the subclass AND make it crash at init in case they are not overriden.

Ex:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def number_of_edges(self):
        pass  # method HAS TO be overloaded in subclass

class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Triangle, self).__init__()

    def number_of_edges(self):
        return 3
```

It seems like the `Python` way is to raise a `NotImplementedError`:

```
def number_of_edges(self):
    raise(NotImplementedError)
```

But it could be beneficial to crash early and detect the lack of implementation during the class instantiation. Why is this not the default, and can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`abc` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) to create an Abstract Base Class.

```
import abc

class Shape(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def number_of_edges(self):
        pass
```

Any method decorated with the [`@abc.abstractmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) will trigger a `TypeError` exception:

```
>>> import abc
>>> class Shape(object):
...     __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     @abc.abstractmethod
...     def number_of_edges(self):
...         pass
...
>>>  
>>> class Triangle(Shape):
...     pass
... 
>>> Triangle('t3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Triangle with abstract methods number_of_edges
>>> class Triangle(Shape):
...     def number_of_edges(self):
...         return 3
... 
>>> Triangle('t3')
<__main__.Triangle object at 0x105f3b8d0>
```

Comment: What's the use of __init__ in Shape? How to instantiate value of name in Shape?

Comment: @NightFurry: you'll have to ask the OP as to why their shapes have a `name` attribute; the `__init__` is there to store that from the given argument when creating an instance.

Comment: Actually i don't know how to instantiate class variable in a metaclass. Just wanted to ask about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can be use Abstact Base Class;

```
import abc
class Shape:
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta   

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def number_of_edges(self):
        pass  # method HAS TO be overloaded in subclass
```

Now, if Triangle class doesn't override the `number_of_edges` method, it will raise exception.